# Number of ways in which a natural number can be expressed as a sum of natural numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> For example $x_1+x_2=4$. The natural solutions are
>   $(1,3);(2,2);(3,1)$.The formula giving the number of ways for this is
>   $\binom{n-1}{r-1}=\binom{3}{1}=3$.But how to find a formula which will
>   return the number of ways as only ${\{1,3\}}$ or ${\{2,2\}}$?

Ok so let me explicitly write my question.

> What is number of ways in which a natural number can be expressed as a
>   sum of natural numbers according to a equation like $x_1+x_2+...+x_r=n$?Is there any formula as such?I mean I don't want repeated solutions like $(1,2,3)$ and then again $(2,3,1)$.

I want a formula which neglects the arrangement of the numbers but only gives the set of numbers which add up to a certain natural number.

So what would be the necessary algorithm or formula?

Comment: Sorry, do you specifically want the sum of TWO natural numbers?  Not general sums like $4=1+1+1+1$?

Comment: @lulu No.Not specifically two.

Comment: So...why is your illustration for $4$ correct?

Comment: Yes.I want general sums actually.

Comment: Actually the number of terms should be equal to number of variables @lulu

Comment: I don't understand.  As the problem currently reads, you are just looking for unordered pairs.  That's what your example illustrates.  If you meant something other than that, you should edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Here there are two variables so I want to express as sum of two natural  numbers.But if there are three variables I would like to express as a sum of 3 numbers.

Comment: @lulu Yes I want number of unordered sets of solutions.The number of elements in the set being equal to number of variables.

Comment: For example if $x_1+x_2+x_3=7$ , 7=2+2+3 or 7=4+1+2 and so on but not 7=1+2+4 as it has already taken it before...

Comment: I still don't understand.  What variables?  Again...please edit the original question to ask the question you intended.  My guess, by the way, is that you are asking about [Partition Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function).

Comment: [this article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionP.html) specifically discusses partitions of fixed length.

Comment: @lulu Seems too complicated and beyond my comprehension.The article you linked :-P.Is it really that complex?

Comment: i edited my question btw...

Comment: Partitions are extremely complicated!  I agree, that's a bit unexpected.  For pairs you can do better...they are just $\{i,n-i\}$ for $i\in [1,\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor]$.  But for general collections, generating functions are really the best approach.

Comment: May be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory) it can help but I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: sums with or without zero ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much depends on whether you want just the *count* of such arrangements or to *list* all of them.

If you were to "neglect" the arrangement of summands, as your example $4=3+1=1+3$ and $4=2+2$ suggests, then you are asking about *integer partitions*.

Efficient ways to count these are known, and it can even be said there exists an *exact formula*.  The book **The Theory of Partitions** by [George Andrews (1976)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Sp7z9sK7RNkC) has the details. See the section [Approximation formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Approximation_formulas) of the Wikipedia article for the convergent series called the Hardy–Ramanujan–Rademacher formula.

If instead you want to (say) write a program to list all the possible integer partitions, then this is an easier task (although such a program might run a long time for all but the smallest inputs).  With the limitation of the largest summand to be allowed, one can express the task recursively:

- If $M$ is the largest summand allowed to express $N$, choose some multiple $k$ of those summands $M$ to be used (descending from $\lfloor N/M \rfloor$ to 0).
- For each such choice $k \ge 0$, recursively list all the possible integer partitions of $N - kM$ allowing summands at most $M-1$ to be used, prefixed by $k$ copies of summand $M$.

Comment: Inserted "not" by mistake in that sentence.Pardon me _/\\_!Thank you for the answer btw.

Comment: nice answer and thank you for you review :)